# String separation C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am readin txt file as bellow. I am trying to separate this data into few different columns.

```
Command sent from hmi(0).ctq[0] to calh(1).ctq[0] v:1,
Command sent from ptov(21) to bo(1).ctq[10] v:0,
Command answer from bo(1) to ptov(21) code:15 - complete,
Event ptof(1).sgn[7] v:0 s:0601,
Command sent from ptuf(1) to bo(1).ctq[5] v:0,
```

I am able to spearate line starting with "Event". I do it in this way. It is easy because it has whitespace character after each important part.

```
List<string> description = list.Select(x => x.System_Description).ToList<string>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("values");

        foreach(string items in description)
        {
            if (items[0] == 'E')
            {
                string[] _columns = items.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
            }
            else
            {

            }
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(items);
```

In this line starting from "Command", I would like to separate it into 4 columns. First one will be just "Command", second one I want to put everything between "from" and "to". Third one will be data after "to" and last one will be value with "v:..". Can you help me somehow, or suggest how can I do it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [RegularExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

Comment: `@"^(?<one>Command)\s.*?from\s(?<two>.*?)\sto\s(?<three>[^\s]+)\s(?<four>.*)$"` that will get you most of the way there, but look in to `Regex` and `Match`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit this regex, that you wrote? I already used before Regex, but I am not advanced and I still find it a bit difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a regular expression to parse the lines. Here is some working code:

```
var text = @"Command sent from hmi(0).ctq[0] to calh(1).ctq[0] v:1,
Command sent from ptov(21) to bo(1).ctq[10] v:0,
Command answer from bo(1) to ptov(21) code:15 - complete,
Event ptof(1).sgn[7] v:0 s:0601,
Command sent from ptuf(1) to bo(1).ctq[5] v:0,";

var lines = text.Split(
  Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
);
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Event) (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>\S+)|(?<C0>Command) (?:answer|sent) from (?<C1>\S+) to (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>.+)),$");
var result = lines
  .Select(line => regex.Match(line))
  .Select(
    match => new {
      C0 = match.Groups["C0"].Value,
      C1 = match.Groups["C1"].Value,
      C2 = match.Groups["C2"].Value,
      C3 = match.Groups["C3"].Value
    }
  );
```

The result is:

```
C0      | C1             | C2             | C3                 |
--------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
Command | hmi(0).ctq[0]  | calh(1).ctq[0] | v:1                |
Command | ptov(21)       | bo(1).ctq[10]  | v:0                |
Command | bo(1)          | ptov(21)       | code:15 - complete |
Event   | ptof(1).sgn[7] | v:0            | s:0601             |
Command | ptuf(1)        | bo(1).ctq[5]   | v:0                |
```

You did not specify how to parse the `Command answer from` line so I took the liberty to make some decision about this myself. Also, I have just created a LINQ query that will parse the lines into a sequence of anonymous objects. See below for where I show how to stuff the results into a `DataTable` (slightly more noisy code).

Here are some highlights of the regular expression:

1. `(?<C0>Event)` is a named group that matches `Event`. The name is `C0` (column zero) and the matched value of the group is accessible in the `Match` object after a match has been performed.
2. `(?:answer|sent)` is a non-capturing group that will match either `answer` or `sent` but what it matches is not captured. The bulk of the regular expression is also made of up a non-capturing group that will match either the `Command` line or the `Event` line.
3. `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters.
4. Starting the regular expression with `^` and ending it with `$` ensures that the entire line is matched.

To put the results in a `DataTable` you can drop the anonymous type and instead use this code (replace the from the `var result = lines` line of code):

```
var matches = lines.Select(line => regex.Match(line));
var dataTable = new DataTable();
foreach (var columnName in new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" })
  dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName);
foreach (var match in matches)
  dataTable.Rows.Add(
    match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(group => group.Value).ToArray()
  );
```

The only tricky part is the `Skip(1)` where the first group in the match is skipped. The first group is the entire match. By skipping that I know that the four remaining groups are C0 to C3 and the values are then used to create the array with the column values for the row.

Since I don't use the group names they can actually be removed from the regular expression. E.g. `(?<C1>\S+)` can be replaced with `(\S+)` etc.

I just picked A, B, C and D as random names for the columns.

Comment: It is a great answer, now I will try to implement it.

Comment: How can I write this column straight to datatable?

Comment: @user2592968: I have updated my answer to show how to write the values into a `DataTable`.

Comment: Ok, I did it this way, but I still have nothing inside my gridview, when I bind it with datatable that I created. Here is my code. I make a foreach loop and then this...

Comment: @user2592968: If you are having trouble making the code behave as you want I suggest that you either run it in isolation or debug it to get a better understanding what is going on. For instance, if a line of text doesn't match the regular expression an empty row is inserted into the `DataTable`.

Comment: Ok, I manage to fix my problem. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method to split the string into an array using space (' ') as your splitting character.  Then, based on your your example file looks you can simply use the correct indexes in the array to get the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = s.Split(',')
    .ToList()
    .Where(
        x=>
        x.Split(' ')[0].Trim() == "Command"
        )
    .Select(
        x => new 
        {
            Command = x.Split(' ')[0],
            Direction = x.Split(' ')[1],
            From = x.Split(' ')[3],
            To = x.Split(' ')[5] ,
            v = x.Split(' ')[6]
        })
    .ToList();
```