# C# insert regex match into datatable

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am looking for lines that will match my regex.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
foreach (var columnName in new[] { "Category", "Device", "Data Type", "Value", "Status" })
dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName);

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:(?<C0>Put) (?<C1>\S+) (?<C2>\S+) (?<C3>\S+) (?<C4>\S+))$");

var matches = lines.Select(line => regex.Match(line));

foreach (var match in matches)dataTable.Rows.Add(match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).ToArray());
```

My input

```
Put this inside datatable spec
```

Now it is putting all matches inside datatable, but in normal order. I would like to able to specify in which column to put each word. For example I want to be able to put word "this" inside column "Value" and so on.

I know from my previous topic  ([String separation C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789475/string-separation-c-sharp/17789986#17789986)) that I can specify somehow match.Group["C0"].Value, but I don't know how to implement it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own order by first instantiating a list with the elements in the order you like and then convert it into an array.

```
  dataTable.Rows.Add((new List<Group>{match.Groups["C0"], match.Groups["C1"]}).ToArray());
```

You could event omit the List<> by directly creating an array of Groups - this works as well:

```
  dataTable.Rows.Add(new Group[] { match.Groups["C1"], match.Groups["C0"] });
```

Comment: I am afraid it is not working, it only gives this message in first column  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group]

Comment: adjusted answer with .ToArray() I forgot that one.